# QT C++ sending variable between forms in Modal View

Tags: c++, forms, qt, variables, modal-dialog

I have a problem sending two integers between forms in the modal view (using QT).
I want the first form to send two integers to the second form (when I click a button) .
The function that is supposed to send the integers (shut_down_timer.cpp):

```
void shut_down_timer::on_setShutDown_clicked()
{
    close();
    timer t;
    t.setHours(5);
    t.setMinutes(6);
    t.setModal(true);
    t.exec();
}
```

the header of the second form (timer.h):

```
class timer;
}

class timer : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    void setHours(int h);
    void setMinutes(int m);
    explicit timer(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~timer();

private slots:
    void on_CloseButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::timer *ui;
    int hours;
    int minutes;


};
```

the function that stores the ints (timer.cpp):

```
void timer::setHours(int h){
    hours=h;
}

void timer::setMinutes(int m){
    minutes=m;
}
```

Can you spot the problem?
Thank you in advance!

FULL CODE:
First from header (shut_down_timer.h):

```
#ifndef SHUT_DOWN_TIMER_H
#define SHUT_DOWN_TIMER_H

#include <QDialog>
#include "timer.h"

namespace Ui {
class shut_down_timer;
}

class shut_down_timer : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit shut_down_timer(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~shut_down_timer();

private slots:
    void on_setShutDown_clicked();

private:
    Ui::shut_down_timer *ui;
    timer *t;
};

#endif // SHUT_DOWN_TIMER_H
```

First form cpp (shut_down_timer.cpp):

```
#include "shut_down_timer.h"
#include "ui_shut_down_timer.h"

shut_down_timer::shut_down_timer(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::shut_down_timer)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

shut_down_timer::~shut_down_timer()
{
    delete ui;
}



void shut_down_timer::on_setShutDown_clicked()
{
    close();
    timer t;
    t.setHours(ui->timeEdit->time().hour());
    t.setMinutes(ui->timeEdit->time().second());
    t.setModal(true);
    t.exec();
}
```

Second form header (timer.h):

```
#ifndef TIMER_H
#define TIMER_H

#include <QDialog>

namespace Ui {
class timer;
}

class timer : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    void setHours(int h);
    void setMinutes(int m);
    explicit timer(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~timer();

private slots:
    void on_CloseButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::timer *ui;
    int hours;
    int minutes;


};

#endif // TIMER_H
```

Second form cpp (timer.cpp):

```
#include "timer.h"
#include "ui_timer.h"
#include "LCDNumber.h"
#include <QFrame>
#include <QLayout>
#include <QString>

timer::timer(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::timer)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QWidget *centralWidget = new QWidget(this);
    LCDNumber *number = new LCDNumber(centralWidget,1,30,0);
    number->setFrameShape(QFrame::NoFrame);
    number->setGeometry(10,10,261,61);
    number->timer->start(1000);
}

timer::~timer()
{
    delete ui;
}

void timer::setHours(int h){
    hours=h;
}

void timer::setMinutes(int m){
    minutes=m;
}

void timer::on_CloseButton_clicked()
{
    close();
}
```

Comment: You say you got a Problem... what is the Problem?

Comment: The secound form (timer) doesn't get the values i send from the first form(shut_down_timer)... idk why.

Comment: I am missing a problem description also. What is the top class definition in your timer.h? Is it some paste fragment? Otherwise you should get a big compile error for that double definition and the closing bracket.

Comment: I will edit the question and add the full code.

Comment: How do you verify, that the values were not passed correctly?

Comment: why do you have timer *t; in shut_down_timer.h but use a local timer in shut_down_timer.cpp? Where is the connection: Button to on_setShutDown_clicked()? Done with QtDesigner?